# Is there any way to recognize multiple usb-uart devices attach to the raspberry?

Tags: android-things

I'm trying to connect 2 usb-uart device to my raspberry with Android for thing.

My problem is I cannot difference my devices because de Api to get the uart devices attach to it only give me a list of string without any descripcion:

```java
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
List<String> deviceList = manager.getUartDeviceList();
```

> List of available devices: [USB1-1.2:1.0, USB1-1.4:1.0]

The only way that I could recognize my uart devices is looking in which port of the raspberry is attached.

[image: raspberry pi usb port]

So, the USB1-1.**2**:1.0 is the specific port that show the figure.

But, if i don't put the device in the correct usb port, the raspberry will not be able to use it and is not scalable.

There is another way to difference the uart devices?

Comment: This has been answered a number of times, see for instance [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name)